# System boots directly to Windows 8 with no GRUB bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, bootloader, boot-repair, grub-efi

Tried boot repair ,the recommended repair could not solve the issue. System still boots directly to Windows 8 with no GRUB. Though GRUB can be accessed during start up by pressing f9 and selecting the boot device as Ubuntu .

Here the link to boot text something. Help guys
 http://paste.ubuntu.com/23522175/

Comment: Please mention the method you used to repair grub.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Done recommended repair using the live boot repair

Comment: Have you tried the "Internal Hard Disk" entry. Boot-Repair copies shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi as fallback or hard drive boot entry. You also have Windows fast start up on, to dual boot from grub and use NTFS partition(s) you need that off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: No, fast start up is turned off. I dont know about this  "Internal Hard Disk" entry though .

Answer (score 2):

This is same case of mine. So I guess you have hp laptop. If this is the case then open you BIOS menu by pressing F10 at startup. Then go to boot options or might be system configuration. There you can see boot options [image]
Then press Enter. There will appear two option.

> 1. Widows Boot Manager (llike similar)
> 2. Ubuntu

After that this will appear
[image: OS BOOT MANAGER]
Well I missed a thing. Here in Uefi boot order there is OSBoot manager. Press Enter.
Then press f5 or f6 that will change the preferences. Here I have Windows as my first preference. You should place windows option at second place by pressing f5 or f6. 
Then press f10 for save and exit.
Hope that helps

Comment: Yes , it is HP laptop but no Ubuntu option in Boot options , just OS boot manager , cd , dvd, usb etc.

Comment: I have made edits now see. I am sending you screen shots of that in few moments. I have to turn my laptop off to take that pic

Comment: And remember to keep secure boot off if you want to install third parties drivers and codecs like your wifi driver etc.

Comment: Thanks , everything is same as the screen-shot except nothing happens when i press  Enter at the OS boot manager

Comment: Send me screenshot

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/DLyqV

Comment: enter doesnt do anyting on OS boot manager