# Dual Booting doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub2, windows-8

just reinstalled ubuntu on a system that already has windows 8, and I installed it along side windows 8, I choose the USB Hard Drive (UEFI) option. But when I restart on put on the system it automatically boots windows and doesn't allow me choose which OS i would prefer to use.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: What brand/model system? Can you from UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 boot ubuntu entry?

Comment: @oldfred I Use HP Envy Sleekbook 14, No OS boot Manager diesn't show any Ubuntu preference

Comment: @oldfred also just saw secure Boot is already disabled.

Comment: Just about every HP needs a work around. Most copy shimx64 to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and boot the fallback or hard drive entry. Boot-Repair now does the copy if you use advanced mode and check the 'use the standard efi file' option. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
 and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114 and: HP Check if Customized UEFI setting
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332681&p=13527216#post13527216

Answer (score 1):

Use f9 there you can see Ubuntu. If you want a permanent repair then you should change OS boot manager preference in your BIOS menu. [See here my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852754/system-boots-directly-to-windows-8-with-no-grub-bootloader/852757#852757)

Comment: OS boot manager, doesn't show me the Ubuntu option, when i press enter it does nothing

Comment: And secure boot is already disabled